# Count Number of Matched Elements in Document with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to count the amount of video thumbnails on a given product page for an ecommerce store, and then output this number on the same page in a particular HTML element.

The desired result is that on the 'Videos' tab there will be the number of videos right next to it. i.e. Videos 17

I've tried to use .length() and .append() to achieve this but am having dramas. I have about 1.5 days jQuery experience so I know I'm doing something wrong here.

```
 $document().ready(function(){
        var numvids = $('.videos').length;
        $('.countvids').append("<p>"+numvids+"</p>");
        });
```

[I've set up a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65BrR/)

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `$document().ready(fn)` is not valid jQuery.  You need `$(document).ready(fn)`.

Comment: so my only issue was where my parenthesis were positioned for $document ?

Comment: Yep, that was the only issue.

Comment: working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/65BrR/5/

Comment: You want to use the shorter jQuery shortcut for `$(document).ready(function() {YOUR CODE HERE});` which is simply `$(function(){YOUR CODE HERE});`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Jquery **$()** is a selector, if you say :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    });
```

it means that execute the block inside that function when my document is loaded complete on the browser, but what you write :

```
$document().ready(function(){
...
});
```

is wrong syntax and is not valid in jquery.

this should work with **length**:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var numvids = $('.videos').length;
        $('.countvids').append("<p>"+numvids+"</p>");
        });
```

or you can use **size()**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var numvids = $('.videos').size();
            $('.countvids').append("<p>"+numvids+"</p>");
            });
```

here is [Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5FNvf/)

you code was like this:

```
$document().ready(function(){
        var numvids = $('.videos').length;
        $('.countvids').append("<p>"+numvids+"</p>");
        });
```

which is wrong

and also you need to include query script file in your page.

you can include it from online like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed and why so we don't have to reverse engineer what your code changed.  Also, why change to `.size()` when `.length` works just fine?

Comment: You still didn't actually explain what you changed.  Is there a reason you make people compare two blocks of code to figure it out?  You can see how simple the explanation can be in my comment to the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

See updated fiddle.

The only error is that you did not include the Jquery link and/or

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65BrR/4/

Comment: yep - I did all the hard work and made such a newbie mistake at the start. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

**$document() is not Correct syntax of jquery , its $(document)**

hope so its solve your problem !

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var numvids = $('.videos').length;
     alert(numvids );
     $('.countvids').append("<p>"+numvids+"</p>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was referencing the a non-existent global function called `$document` isntead of calling `$(document)`. *As it happens, your code would have worked, as-is, if it had been preceded by this:*

```
var $document = $(document).ready;
```

*But this is purely for amusement and is not very practical or readable code :)*

### Use the document-ready *shortcut* syntax

You really want to use the shorter jQuery shortcut. Instead of `$(document).ready(function() {YOUR CODE HERE});` use `$(function(){YOUR CODE HERE})`;

### e.g.

```
$(function(){
     var numvids = $('.videos').length;
     alert(numvids );
     $('.countvids').append("<p>"+numvids+"</p>");
});
```

*This results in shorter code and is becoming so commonplace you might as well get used to it :)*